# Wordpress style.css not work on page

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been looking for hours for why `style.css` is not loading/apply/working online, really need your help! Thanks!

My situation is kind of weird, it works on my `header.php`, but not on the page and `footer.php`

I was working on custom post type and advance custom field, and try to do embed in one section, then I refresh the page, then my all style is gone.

Here's what I have tried, not working so far...

1. I deactivated all the plugins.
2. Clean cache and refresh, I even restart the server.
3. Delete .htaccess and recreate new a one.
4. I turn on WP debugging tools, no error show.
5. I checked chrome console, no red error. In the source, I believe they load the style.css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcLQ6.png)
6. My header link to css

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

My `functions.php` have the `wp_enqueue_script` already, anything I can add?

```
function new_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'new-theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'new-theme-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', [], '20151215', TRUE );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'new-theme-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', [], '20151215', TRUE );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new_theme_scripts' );
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no need to add stylesheet to your function.php file. Just check the style you wrote is working of not. I think there is some error in the css file. So that it is not working. Can i see the site ?

Comment: Your code looking fine which you post, if you can post full code here then I can check but you can try few things :-
- Create a new theme and in that place your code and test whether its working or not.
- You can try css rename as well for testing and also test css validation from online tool 
https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say 'it works on my header.php, but not on the page and footer.php'? Could you describe what you mean by 'it works on my header.php' please?

Comment: @Ranjit Because I find some people have the issue with plugin rewrite their CSS, and the solution is put wp_enquenue on the functions.php. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @Abhijeet it's on my local server, so I don't have a link can share. sorry!

Comment: @Ruby Please find the error with your css file. I am sure it is with the css file.

Comment: @Noah Whitmore My CSS style does show up in my header section(Navbar, logo), but not in the rest of page, even I put <?php get_header(); ?> on the page-home.php  Thank you for the comment!

Comment: Can see the view source in the rest of your pages and look whether css file is coming or not ?

Comment: It's tough to rule out an error in your CSS file without seeing everything. If styles are being applied to your header area and not the rest of the page, do you maybe have a `main` element of a `div` that is causing styles not to be applied to the rest of the page? Or perhaps your stylesheet is attempting to apply styles like `main > p` but you do not have a `main` element on the page, so the styles are not being applied?

Comment: @Ruby you particular css not apply or style.css is not added in your project ?If particular css not working that means your css is breaking just validate it once.you can push your code on github so that we can see because without seeing the code its not easy to find out the issue :(

Comment: @Ranjit Yes, I check the source code in the console, when I click my CSS link, the file does show up. Thank you.

Comment: @Noah Whitmore Sorry I don't have a <main> element on my HTML. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @Abhijeet Thank you, but my files it's really big, it will take a long time, I try couple things to see. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Ruby its fine :) , but you can also share code with TV i shortout many issues through that ..or you can reach me through skyp or mail

Comment: @Abhijeet Thank you so much, I just redo everything again, and it works now, I believe it's my CSS have an issue, which it doesn't show up any error. Really appreciated your help!